# How can I get the control type (UIElement) from FrameworkElementFactory in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, uielement, frameworkelementfactory

I'm working on a large plugin component to a quite larger application. 90% of this particular View component is extremely dynamic (database driven) and done programmatically. There is a particular reason for that (minimal XAML), so think outside the box. And no, I can't go back and retool a code base that consists of 1000's of lines of code...that's a future version.

I can set values, bindings and add handlers, via the FrameworkElementFactory, but need to access the control itself to do other tasks. One task would be to add a ToolTipService to each FrameworkElement. I'm able to do it if I add a Loaded Event to each derived control, then manage it through the handler by adding it to an indexed object collection, but this is a really ugly way of doing it.

I put together this small snippet (below) for testing, but it encompasses the issue at hand.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="FrameworkElementFactory_Control_Testing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrameworkElementFactory_Control_Testing"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="500"
        Height="300"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                    Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Vertical" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace FrameworkElementFactory_Control_Testing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            GridObjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<GridObject>() { new GridObject() };
            //GridObjectCollection.Add(new GridObject());

            DoTheGrid();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<GridObject> GridObjectCollection { get; set; }
        public GridObject CurrentGridObject { get; set; }

        private void DoTheGrid()
        {
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            dg.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dg.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dg.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
            dg.CanUserSortColumns = false;
            dg.IsReadOnly = true;
            dg.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
            dg.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single;
            dg.SelectedItem = CurrentGridObject;
            dg.ItemsSource = GridObjectCollection;

            DataGridTemplateColumn dgTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            FrameworkElementFactory factoryControl = null;

            TextBlock headerName = new TextBlock() { Text = "Button Type" };

            dgTemplateColumn.Header = headerName;

            factoryControl = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
            factoryControl.SetValue(Button.MarginProperty, new Thickness(1));
            factoryControl.SetValue(Button.WidthProperty, Convert.ToDouble("70"));
            factoryControl.SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, Convert.ToDouble("24"));
            factoryControl.SetValue(Button.NameProperty, "btnCLICK_ME");
            factoryControl.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "Click Me");
            factoryControl.AddHandler(Button.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ButtonLoaded_Click));

            DataTemplate cellTemplateControl = new DataTemplate();
            cellTemplateControl.VisualTree = factoryControl;
            dgTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplateControl;
            dgTemplateColumn.CanUserSort = false;
            dg.Columns.Add(dgTemplateColumn);

            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dg);
        }

        private void ButtonLoaded_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;

            //add btn to indexed collection for future reference (this is lame)
        }
    }
}
```

**GridObject.cs**

```
namespace FrameworkElementFactory_Control_Testing
{
    public class GridObject
    {
        public GridObject()
        { }

    }
}
```

Any constructive help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time folks.

CT